# Consolidating rows in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that has a blank line after every weekending - each section will have several rows that I need to consolidate by person with totals in each column - so in the example below I would need 1 line for Annette for 3/4/16 with a total for each of the last 4 columns (E, F, G, H) and 1 line for Josh and so on for each name on the 3/4/16 (column B) - then this would be repeated for the next week 10/4/16 and so on for the whole year.

Can you help me with a script for this?

```
Name    Wk End Date P/E Date    Shift   Sleeps changed  Units       
Annette 03/04/2016          7.50    7.50    17.25   129.375
Annette 03/04/2016          7.50    7.50    22.43   168.225
Annette 03/04/2016          7.50    7.50    27.60   207
Josh    03/04/2016          8.00    8.00    6.70    53.6
Josh    03/04/2016          7.00    7.00    8.50    59.5

David   10/04/2016          11.00   11.00   7.50    82.5
David   10/04/2016          8.00    8.00    7.20    57.6
David   10/04/2016          11.00   11.00   7.50    82.5
Tomasz  10/04/2016          7.50    7.50    7.20    54
Tomasz  10/04/2016          7.50    7.50    7.25    54.375
Tomasz  10/04/2016          7.00    7.00    7.20    50.4
```

Comment: "*Can you help me with a script for this?*" - In short? Very unlikely... Sorry, but SO won't code for you (sometimes), but we will help your already existing code! Give it a try yourself and if you run into errors in your code, please come back :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use VBA?

You should be able to solve this easily with a pivot table.

Make the range of the pivot table the columns without row numbers A:F (vs A1:F375)

[image]

I added additional data for Annette and Josh for Oct to illustrate how the pivot table could help

[image]

Here's the Pivot Table

[image]